# Google Calendar Data API Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, oauth-ruby

We're using Oauth to grab Calendar event data. I have successfully authorized the token and exchange it for an access token. When I perform a get request to the API endpoint I get a page that says "Moved Temporarily" with a link to something like https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default?gsessionid=xxxxxxxxxxxx

I'd like to interpret the response, whether it's json or xml but I can't get beyond the redirect it's throwing out. Any idea how to follow this?

Here's my call to the feed:

```
    access_token = current_user.google.client
    response = access_token.get(ConsumerToken::GOOGLE_URL).body
```

Comment: Hi, which Ruby library did you use to access the Google Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just dealt with this myself.  It says "Moved Temporarily" because it's a redirect, which the oauth gem unfortunately doesn't follow automatically.  You can do something like this:

```
calendar_response = client.get "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default"
if calendar_response.kind_of? Net::HTTPFound # a.k.a. 302 redirect
  calendar_response = client.get(calendar_response['location'])
end
```

This might be worthy of a patch to oauth...

Comment: Hi, which Ruby library did you use to access the Google Docs?

Comment: @Crashalot I use the [OAuth Ruby gem](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) with [oauth-plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin).

Comment: Thank! You so much! This was the last step in my oauth quest and now it works  :-) .